# Changing shaders dynamically in OpenGL application

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to change color of objects in my program with shaders - fragment shader to be precise.

I have two shader programs: box, triangle (names are random - just for easier reference). For both programs I use this same vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

vec3 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

and then i am using my `box_shader` program:

```
box_shader.Use();

// Create camera transformation
view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
glm::mat4 projection;
projection = glm::perspective(camera.Zoom, (float)WIDTH/(float)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

// Get the uniform locations
GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "model");
GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "view");
GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "projection");
// Pass the matrices to the shader
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

later in the program I'd like to use `triangle_shader` program. What I was trying is:

```
triangl_shader.Use()
DrawTraingles();
```

So I don't call again `glGetUniformLocation`, instead use those created earlier. Unfortunately with this I don't see triangles drawn with `DrawTraingles()`, although, when I don't switch shader program they appear.

For my shaders loading and use I use this class: [learnopengl](http://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?type=header&code=shader) so everything is there regarding `Use()` function.

Can someone tell me what I should do to make use of different shaders?

**EDIT:**

What I've figured out was add `glGetUniformLocations` after `packet_shader.Use()`, so it looks now like this:

```
packet_shader.Use();

// Get the uniform locations
modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(packet_shader.Program, "model");
viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(packet_shader.Program, "view");
projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(packet_shader.Program, "projection");
// Pass the matrices to the shader
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

Although, I am not sure if this is the best idea in the matter of performance. Can someone tell me is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniforms are *per-program* state in the GL. So there are two issues here:

1. The uniform locations might be completely different in each program. For each program, you'll have to query the uniform locations, and have to store them separately for late use.
2. The uniform values have to be set for each program seperately. Even if you consider two programs "sharing" the same uniform, this is not the case. All the `glUniform*()` setters affect only the program *currently in use*. Since each of your program has its own `model`, `view` and `projection` uniform, you have to set these for each program, everytime they change. Currently, it looks like you never set those for the second program, so they are left at ther initial defaults of all zeros.

If you want to share uniforms between different programs, you might consider looking into [Uniform Buffer Objects (UBOs)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object).

Comment: I guess, I've just figured it out by myself, when you were answering :) So does it mean, that my edit is optimal approach in the matter of performance?

Comment: The optimum for performance will always depend on the specific scenario you are interested in. You definitively should avoid querying the uniform locations more than once. Do this just once after each program was linked. For updating the values: If you need two programs per frame, you'll have to set your transformation matrices twice per frame, or use UBOs.